# Capitalize \dayofweekname first letter

Tags: datetime, uppercase

I'm working with dates, in particular with `\dayofweekname`. Is there any way to capitalize the first letter (i.e. the output *monday* should become *Monday*)? I tried with `\MakeUppercase` and `\capitalisewords` but the compiler doesn't even output a file (I suppose because of the internal structure of the commands, which collide).

Here it is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, italian]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{datetime}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\dayofweekname{12}{03}{2023} 12/03/2023}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, I forgot it. Meanwhile, I also realized that in English it works as you say, but in other languages, like Italian, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowercased day-of-week names in Italian are hardcoded in `dt-italian.def`, which is shipped with `datetime` package.

```tex
% dt-italian.def
\providecommand{\dayofweeknameiditalian}[1]{%
\ifcase#1\relax
\or domenica%
\or luned\`{\i}%
\or marted\`{\i}%
\or mercoled\`{\i}%
\or gioved\`{\i}%
\or venerd\`{\i}%
\or sabato%
\fi}%
\global\let\dayofweeknameiditalian\dayofweeknameiditalian
```

A simple redefinition should work, but I don't know if all-lowercased day-of-week names are needed in Italian.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt, italian]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{datetime}

\renewcommand{\dayofweeknameiditalian}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax
  \or Domenica%
  \or Luned\`{\i}%
  \or Marted\`{\i}%
  \or Mercoled\`{\i}%
  \or Gioved\`{\i}%
  \or Venerd\`{\i}%
  \or Sabato%
  \fi}%

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\dayofweekname{12}{03}{2023} 12/03/2023}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remark: `datetime` is obsolete and replaced by `datetime2`.  But it seems per OP's use case `datetime2` doesn't has an improvement.  The day-of-week is still all-lowercased, for instance "domenica").

```tex
\documentclass[12pt, italian]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% also need package datetime2-italian
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\DTMcomputedayofweekindex{2023-03-12}\dowindex
\rhead{\DTMweekdayname{\dowindex} 12/03/2023}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: I'm so lucky just familiarizing with `datetime` and next day I discover the existence of `datetime2`. And for the same reason as this post, same language too!